# How to display a different path on the same components in vue

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I am trying to replicate the `https://uk.indeed.com` landing page functionality. On the main page, when you click on a job, it displays the job details on the right.

I could achieve a similar result with a code like this

#job.vue

```
<div class="" v-for="job in jobs" :key="job.id">
   <div @click="showJobDetails(job)"> {{ job.title}} </div> 
    ...
```

Then on the right, I can do something like this

```
    <div>
      <h1>{{ selectedJob.title }}</h1>
    </div>
    ...
```

#scripts

```
<script setup>
....
import {ref,} from 'vue'
const jobs = ref(JobData)

const selectedJob = ref(null);

function showJobDetails(job) {
selectedJob.value = job;  
}


</script>
```

This code just finds an instance of the job and prints it on the right without using the path to the job-details page. However on the indeed website. it makes a full request to the server and the URL changes to the specified job path

Here is an example of what their URL looks like

`https://uk.indeed.com/?advn=9032543092765405&vjk=f0c64867d998ec7b`

With my setup, My URL always remains the same like

`localhost:5171/jobs`

So my question is how can you render the full details path on the right side of the page without navigating to the details.vue. I use a Singlejob.vue to render the  job details

#paths

```
  ....
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/jobs',
      name: 'jobs',
      component: JobsPage
      
    },
    {
      path: '/details/:id',
      name: 'details',
      component: SingleJob
      
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You could make the '/details/:id', as a child route of the jobs , for e.g:-  children: [
    { path: '/details/:id', name: 'detailsView', component: SingleJob },
  ]      and add a <RouterView/> in jobs component to display it on click . It should be a <RouterLink :to='/details/${job.id}`>.. instead of a div with click event.